# Preventing SQL Injection for iOS Swift App

Tags: php, ios, swift, mysqli, sql-injection

I am designing an iOS mobile app in Swift which uses a remote SQL database for its backend. This app has a lot of interactions with the database, due to this I want to ensure it is safe from SQL injection. My first idea was to check in Swift if the text in the `UITextView` contains any blacklisted words, however after reading this:

[image]

I'm not sure if blacklisting is a good idea; although I'm not sure about the degree to which these problems affect mobile apps; as this was written about websites. Another thing I read about was using parametirised queries, although I don't really understand what this means exactly as most examples I read were designed for websites as well; the way I currently connect to my database is through sending a `POST` request from a `NSURLSession` to a `PHP` script on my server. This is a typical example of what I do in my PHP script :

```
 $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
 $second_field = $_POST['second_field'];

 $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***","***");

 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO my_table (user_id, second_field) VALUES ('$user_id', '$second_field')");
```

Comment: @mario I read that question before posting this, but that was related mainly to websites as well and it didn't help me that much

Comment: Irrelevant where it originated. Input is input, no matter the source.